# Android checkout my library and project in a same time

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I created an Android library project and an app project which is use my library. I sent into svn:

svn/trunk/library and svn/trunk/app.

Can I checkout both under Eclipse in a same time? So my destination that I checkout just svn/trunk and the library project and app project will be create. Thanks

Comment: Just a side note, Maven support multi-module project where you can checkout, import a group of project in a same time, more reading [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the 2 projects in svn and In that case you need to checkout the app and library project separately to eclipse.